# Can´t show validation messages

Tags: validation, cakephp, file-upload

I am a newbie. I have tried many solutions on other posts but I just can't get it right. The mesages on my validation simply don't show up, but the value of the file input field gets null if the size validation does not pass, but it seems that the extension valdiation is not working as well. Why are no messages showing up and the extension validation not working?
I am using CakePHP 2.4.4.

**Controller**

```
    public function admin_upload_image(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Inserir Fotografias');
        if(!$this->Session->check('User')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
            $this->redirect(array(
                            'controller' => 'users',
                            'action' => 'login'));
        }

        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
          /*  $file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];*/
        $file = array(
                'GalleryImage' => array(
                'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
                                        )
                );
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);

            $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');

            $this->GalleryImage->create();
           //debug($file);
           //die;
            if($this->GalleryImage->save($file)){
                $validationErrors = $this->GalleryImage->invalidFields();
                $this->Session->setFlash($validationErrors['path']); // named key of the rule
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Evento guardado com sucesso.'));
            }
            //else{

                //$error = $this->Notification->validationErrors;
                //$this->set('error', $error);

                //$this->Session->setFlash(__($error), 'Flash/warning');
            //}
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('GalleryImage',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Guardar'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success','formnovalidate' => false)) ;
echo $this->Form->end();
/*if ($this->Form->isFieldError('path')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('path');
}*/
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
  class GalleryImage extends AppModel{
    public $displayField ='path';
    public $useTable = 'gallery_images';
    //public $actsAs = array('MultipleDisplayFields' => array('fields' => array('path', 'id')));
    var $name = 'GalleryImage';
    var $validate= array(
        'path' => array(
            'is_valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.',
                'last' => true),
            'size' => array(
                'rule' => array('fileSize','<=','1.5MB'),
                'message' => 'O ficheiro deve ter um tamanho igual ou inferior a 1.5MB.',
                'last' => true),
            'extension' => array(
                'rule' => array('extension', array('gif','jpeg','png','jpg')),
                'message'=> 'A imagem deve estar num formato gif, jpeg, png ou jpg.',
                'last' => true)
            )
        );
  }
?>
```

**debug($file)**

```
\app\Controller\GalleriesController.php (line 58)
array(
'GalleryImage' => array(
    'path' => '1604710_722861904399871_963210258_n.jpg'
)
)
```

**pr($this->GalleryImage->invalidFields());**

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: gallery_images [APP\Controller\GalleriesController.php, line 50]
Notice (8): Undefined index: gallery_images [APP\Controller\GalleriesController.php, line 53]
Notice (8): Undefined index: gallery_images [APP\Controller\GalleriesController.php, line 53]
Array
(
[path] => Array
    (
        [0] => Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.
        [1] => Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.
    )

)
```

Comment: Can you debug using `if ($this->GalleryImage->save($file)) /*your code*/ else {pr($this->ModelName->invalidFields());}` in the controller? To check if you are not getting the errors from the model or if your controller receives them correctly but the view doesn't display them. Update your question with the result of `pr()` (or lack of it if you don't get an error array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Form->input

"building block" functions such as [checkbox](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3acheckbox), [radio](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aradio), [select](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aselect) and [file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3afile) are *just* the input. The normal way to generate forms is to use the [input](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3ainput) (or [inputs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3ainputs)) method:

```
echo $this->Form->input('path', array('type' => 'file'));
```

### Or explicitly render errors

Alternatively, you can render the validation errors explicitly:

```
echo $this->Form->file('path');
echo $this->Form->error('path');
```

Comment: I used the `echo $this->Form->error('path');` and that shows an error, but is the wrong one. I get the `is_valid` rule message insted of the `size` one as I was trying to upload a file that exceds the 1.5MB

Comment: I used to a 12MB image to test, and my php upload limit is set to 20MB. What I need to know is just why the messages aren't showing, and why i am getting the wrong error using the code you posted.

Comment: so you are saying that this is being caused with the uploaded file size  limits?

Comment: Ok I will mark your question as the solution. Thanks.